# How to pass value from selectd option to controller with playframework

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

I am trying to make an ajax call with a url based on the selected value of an dropdown.

So far I have something like:

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'@{action($(this).val())}',
        success:function(report){
           alert('success');
        },
        fail:function(error){
            alert('error:'+error);         
        }
    }
    });
```

The template will not compile and complaun about the url line.

My problem is that I dont know how to convert the value returned from jquery into a parameter to be routed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Solved using jsRoute

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    var route = #{jsRoute @action(':field') /}
    $.ajax({
        url: route.url({field: $('#select').val()}),
        type: route.method,
        success:function(report){
           alert('success');
        },
        fail:function(error){
            alert('error:'+error);         
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about playframework, but I know about jQuery ajax. So here is a solution, may be it help you to fix your problem. In jQuery Ajax method we can send data by POST or GET method. To do this we have to set type option in ajax options. To send data we have to set data parameter in ajax options which contains all of tha data which we want to post to the url.

```
$('#select').change(function() {

 var params = {myvar:$("#select :selected").val()};

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",       
    url:'path to controller',
    data: params,
    success:function(report){
       alert('success');
    },
    fail:function(error){
        alert('error:'+error);         
    }
  });
});
```